# Colors are different in literally-drawing a real time collaborative board

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, togetherjs

I'm using Literally-Drawing which is real time collaborative drawing board.

Here is the Github and Demo link:

[Github Literally-Drawing](https://github.com/MrSaints/Literally-Drawing)

[Demo Link](http://fabric.fyianlai.com/Fabric.html)

This Repository is using two different libraries, one is Fabricjs and the second one is togetherjs, Initially there is only one default "PencilBrush" tool I wanted to add more tools into this but before that I was testing if I can dynamically change the color to "#ccc" or anything and brush type to "CircleBrush" They have connected together both the above mentioned libraries in the "Fabric-Whiteboard.js" file. There are two major functions WB.Core and WB.Collabrative. Core is creating the canvas and collabtive is pushing the data to Togetherjs server so that other browsers who are in the session can listen.

I have made some changes into Core.prototype._createCanvas function within WB.Core function originally it was only creating the canvas so I changed it to add "CircleBrush"

**Originally**

```
Core.prototype._createCanvas = function(id) 
{
  return new fabric.Canvas(id);
};
```

**Changed to**

```
Core.prototype._createCanvas = function(id) 
{
  var canvasCreate = new fabric.Canvas(id);
      canvasCreate.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric['CircleBrush'](canvasCreate);
      canvasCreate.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#CCCCCC";
  return canvasCreate;
};
```

Now this part is working fine i guess because it is giving any error also i have made some change in the "drawStart" within WB.Collaborate function.

**Originally**

```
this.TJS.hub.on('drawStart', function(data) 
{
  var _base, _name;

  if ((_base = _this.client)[_name = data.clientId] == null) 
  {
      _base[_name] = new fabric['PencilBrush'](canvas); // origianlly
  }

  return _this.client[data.clientId].onMouseDown(data.point);
});
```

**Problem:**
The problem is I want the same drawing to be broadcasted to other sessions and if I add following two lines it gives me an error of "Cannot set property 'color' of undefined" where as I can override the default value within WB.core successfully.

**Tried to Change it to:**

```
this.TJS.hub.on('drawStart', function(data) 
{
  var _base, _name;

  if ((_base = _this.client)[_name = data.clientId] == null) 
  {
        var testCanvas = new fabric['CircleBrush'](canvas); // origianlly
        testCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#ccc";

        _base[_name] = testCanvas;
  }

  return _this.client[data.clientId].onMouseDown(data.point);
});
```

**JSFiddle:**

Here is the JsFiddle I tried to make but for some reason real time collabration is not working on both my version and original one

**MyJsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/mwgi2005/p7cwu9ao/7/

This is what it looks like, I have set the color to grey and tool type to "CircleBrush". When I draw in parent Window to the left, it is drawing in grey color where as the child window is drawing in the black which is the default color defined in the fabric library, and vice versa.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you want to offer a JS Fiddle, do go ahead, but asking people to edit it to fix it is a bit like asking people to do your work for you. Someone may yet still do that, but it is better to assume people will give comments and answers that are clues on your journey, rather than a finished piece of software.

Comment: OK, I understand what is it you suggest that i should do ?

Comment: As above, I think a JS Fiddle might be helpful. My feedback was mostly just to adjust your expectations about how much work it is OK to ask of volunteers. It may have just been a wording problem - sometimes it sounds like a poster is asking someone to do their work, even though that is not their intention `:-)`.

Comment: Ok, What I'll do is make a jsfiddle also change some wording to make it look like that i need a direction I don't want anyone to do my work, I appreciate your response and help

Comment: No need to labour that point in my opinion - I removed the "fix it for me" already. "Here is my JS Fiddle" is fine.